# I need help implementing user info popup in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Clicking on user avatar icon, I'm showing user info popup. Toggle works great but the problem other popups doesn't hide. Only one popup should be shown at once. Problem can be checked here.

https://int-app.guidanceguide.com/parenting/guides/home

I'm using popup state in every popup component.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing the first bit about your code.

Comment: No problem, I got it working. Thanks anyway. I used mousedown listener on document and set unique key that could be recognized from the popup component then check if event.target has that unique key, don't do anything otherwise hide popup.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to create a variables for each popup and assigned it value to false initially. then it is set to true when it is need to work .

eg

```
open=false;

------
some code
-----

 handleUpdate = (e) =>
{
this.open=true;
-----some code----
}

--------

then in the JSX part
 <Popup open={this.open} id="popup_id"  >
<div>----</div>
-------------(put your JSX here)
</Popup>
~~~
```